# Discord Mentions in Embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I know you can't mention inside the actual embed, but how do i mention outside of the embed? like as content (message)? Rn, i am using a python script to send a webhook like this:

Code:

```
        message = prepare_webhooks.discord()
        embed = message.embed()
        embed.title = f"Done"
        embed.add_field("username", item.username)
        embed.add_field("mention", "<@&799799447483187210>")
        embed.image.url = item.avatar
        message.embeds.append(embed)
        message = json.loads(json.dumps(
            message, default=lambda o: o.__dict__))
        x = requests.post(webhook_link, json=message)
```

Any word on this thx

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use mention in an embed: in field's value and in the embed's description.
Here's a basic command example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def mention(ctx, member=None):
    member = member or ctx.author
    embed = Embed(description=member.mention)
    ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If you still want to mention out of the embed, just pass the mention before passing your embed:

```py
#In a command
ctx.send(member.mention, embed=embed)

#In a on_message event
message.channel.send(member.mention, embed=embed)
```

Reference : [`discord.abc.Messageable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Comment: I want it to ping people, in the value field it doesnt ping. It shows up but doesnt ping

Comment: You can't ping members in an embed. If you meant to ping people, you could have included it in your question. Sending the mention outside the embed (second part of my answer) will ping the member.